# Battery charge management on Ideapad

Tags: linux, linux-mint, battery, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Ideapad P500 with Linux Mint installed. For some reason the battery only charges up to 59% and then it stops. I've seen [similar problems](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/plugged-in-not-charging-windows-7-solution/) solved for Windows, but not for Linux Mint. Is there a similar step-by-step process or power management software that I can install to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to a setting in Lenovo's proprietary Energy Manager. If you had Windows previously and had enabled "conservation mode," it was limiting your battery charge to 55-60% to increase the duration for which you can get the maximum out of your battery.

You will probably have to boot into Windows, install the utility and disable conservation mode. As far as I have searched on this, there is no other way to get this done.